# Structure of Finite Field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am learning that finite field $GF(p^n)\cong Z_p\oplus Z_p\oplus...\oplus Z_p$ under addition and the set of nonzero elements of $GF(p^n)\cong Z_{p^n-1}$

The corollary of this theorem says that let $a$ be a generator of the group of nonzero elements of $GF(p^n)$ under multiplication. Then $a$ is algebraic over $GF(p)$ of degree $n$. The book says it because $[GF(p)(a):GF(p)]=[GF(p^n):GF(p)]=n$. I don't understand that why $[GF(p)(a):GF(p)]=[GF(p^n):GF(p)]$. Is it because $GF(p)(a)\cong GF(p^n)?$. If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the isomorphism is sufficient, because a set of size $p^n$ can only be a vector space over $\mathrm{GF}(p)$ of dimension $n$, but in fact $\mathrm{GF}(p)(a)=\mathrm{GF}(p^n)$ (literal equality, not isomorphism) which makes
$$[\mathrm{GF}(p)(a):\mathrm{GF}(p)]=[\mathrm{GF}(p^n):\mathrm{GF}(p)]$$
rather obvious (these quantities both being equal to $n$).

Remember, given a field $L$, a subfield $F\subset L$, and an element $\beta\in L$, the field $F(\beta)$ is defined to be the "smallest" subfield of $L$ containing $F$ and the element $\beta$, which is equivalent to
$$F(\beta)=\left\{\tfrac{f(\beta)}{g(\beta)}\in L:f,g\in F[x],\;g(\beta)\neq 0\right\}\subset L$$
So here we have $L=\mathrm{GF}(p^n)$, and $F=\mathrm{GF}(p)$, and $\beta=a$, and we're looking at the subfield $\mathrm{GF}(p)(a)$ of $\mathrm{GF}(p^n)$. Since it contains $a$, it also contains $a,a^2,\ldots,a^{p^n-1}$ which comprises every non-zero element of $\mathrm{GF}(p^n)$. Since $\mathrm{GF}(p)$ already contained zero, the field $\mathrm{GF}(p)(a)$ must have every element of $\mathrm{GF}(p^n)$ in it, and it can't contain anything else (since it's by definition a subfield of $\mathrm{GF}(p^n)$) so they must be equal.

Comment: Just recall that $a\in \operatorname{GF}(p^n)$ and all nonzero elements of $\operatorname{GF}(p^n)$ are powes of $a$ ...